# how to add / sync google calendar?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sync, calendar, pac-rom

I have a **Xaomi Redmi Note 4G** and have installed `PAC-ROM-asrupesh-UNOFFICIAL-PORT.zip` from [XDA - [ROM][PORT] PAC ROM UNOFFICIAL for Redmi Note 4G Single Sim](http://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-note/development/rom-pac-rom-unofficial-redmi-note-4g-t3093908). I followed the steps from the forum to install the ROM.

Now I do not have my Gmail Calendar. If I go to `Calendar -> Settings` I can see my Gmail account but no other calendar. If I hit **Add Account** there is no Gmail account.

If I go to `Settings -> Accounts -> Google Account` and click my Gmail account I want the calendar to be in my mobile, but I cannot see an option to sync calendar. It is not there.

Any idea how to add the Gmail Calender to my current ROM?

Comment: So what I did is to install Google Calendar and it did all that needed to be done so I can see my gmail calendar in android (or is that CM) native calendar application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked calendar app is installed in your phone or not? I mean have you checked calendar app under Settings → App → Application? Search there and  if you find it there then start its service. You can than access it.

Read this Google support article: [Sync problems with the Google Calendar app](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6261951?hl=en&ref_topic=6185103&vid=1-635800552804586756-3291784092)

Comment: That's what is interesting. If I go to Play and search for Google Calendar then I am able to install it. But then what app do I use then? CM calendar?